# How to put file pointer in header file just for my modules?

Tags: c

I am creating a module for a club management system. I want to put the file pointer in the header file just for my modules. I try to put in each function but the program didn't work. How do I do it?

file pointer from redo.c

```
int main() {
    fp = fopen("staff.dat", "rb+");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        fp = fopen("staff.dat", "wb+");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("\nCannot open file...");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    
}
```

this is redo.c (program)

```
#include "Header.h"
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<conio.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

struct staff
{
    char name[40];
    int id[7];
    int age[3];
    char position[20];
};
struct staff s;


long int recsize = sizeof(s);

FILE* fp, * ft;


void addrecord();
void deleterecord();
void displayrecord();
void modifyrecord();
void searchrecord();
void showrecord();
void staffmenu();

char another;

int menu()
{
    int funsType;


    system("cls");
    printf("1) Staff Information\n");
    printf("2) Facility Information\n");
    printf("3) Member Information\n");
    printf("4) Booking Information\n");
    printf("5) Facility Usage Information\n");

    printf("Enter your requirement: ");
    scanf("%d", &funsType);
    switch (funsType) {
    case 1: staffmenu(); break;
    case 2: printf("2"); break;
    case 3: printf("3"); break;
    case 4: printf("4"); break;
    case 5: printf("5"); break;
    default: printf("Please choose the correct number");

    }
    return 0;
}


int main() {
    fp = fopen("staff.dat", "rb+");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        fp = fopen("staff.dat", "wb+");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("\nCannot open file...");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    
}

void staffmenu() {
    system("cls");
    int choice;
    printf("1. ADD RECORD\n");

    printf("2. DELETE RECORD\n");

    printf("3. DISPLAY RECORDS\n");

    printf("4. MODIFY RECORD\n");

    printf("5. SEARCH RECORD\n");

    printf("6. SHOW RECORD\n");

    printf("7. EXIT\n");

    printf("ENTER YOUR CHOICE...\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        addrecord();
        break;
    case 2:
        deleterecord();
        break;
    case 3:
        displayrecord();
        break;
    case 4:
        modifyrecord();
        break;
    case 5:
        searchrecord();
        break;
    case 6:
        showrecord();
        break;
    case 7:
        fclose(fp);
        exit(0);
        break;
    default:
        printf("INVALID CHOICE ! Click any key to continue...\n");
        getch();
        staffmenu();
    }
}


void addrecord()
{
    system("cls");

    char another;


    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);

    printf("Enter ID : ");
    scanf("%s", &s.id);

    printf("Enter Name : ");
    scanf("%s", s.name);

    printf("Enter Age : ");
    scanf("%s", &s.age);

    printf("Enter Position : ");
    scanf("%s", s.position);

    fwrite(&s, recsize, 1, fp);

    printf("Want to add another record (Y/N) : ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", &another);
    while (another == 'y')
        addrecord();
    while (another == 'n')
        staffmenu();

}


void deleterecord()
{
    system("cls");
    char empname[50];
    char another;

    printf("                                         ===============================================\n");
    printf("                                         ||              DELETE STAFF / MEMBER         ||\n");
    printf("                                         ===============================================\n\n");
    printf("                                          Enter employee name to delete : ");
    scanf("%s", empname);

    ft = fopen("temp.dat", "wb+");
    rewind(fp);

    while (fread(&s, recsize, 1, fp) == 1) {
        if (strcmp(s.name, empname) != 0)
            fwrite(&s, recsize, 1, ft);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(ft);
    remove("staff.dat");
    rename("temp.dat", "staff.dat");
    fp = fopen("staff.dat", "rb+");
    printf("\n");
    printf("                                          Want to delete another record (y/n) :");
    fflush(stdin);

    scanf("%s", &another);
    while (another == 'y')
        deleterecord();
    while (another == 'n')
        staffmenu();

}


void displayrecord()
{
    system("cls");


    rewind(fp);

    printf("==========================================================\n");
    printf("ID\t\tNAME\t\tAGE\tPOSITION\n", s.id, s.name, s.age, s.position);
    printf("==========================================================\n");

    while (fread(&s, recsize, 1, fp) == 1)
        printf("\n%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t%s", s.id, s.name, s.age, s.position);

    printf("\n\n\n\t");
    printf("Press any key to back to menu......");
    if (getch())
        staffmenu();
}

void modifyrecord()
{
    system("cls");
    char empname[50];
    char another;

    printf("Enter employee name to modify : ");
    scanf("%s", empname);
    fp = fopen("staff.dat", "rb+");
    rewind(fp);

    while (fread(&s, recsize, 1, fp) == 1) {

        if (strcmp(s.name, empname) == 0) {
            printf("\nEnter new id:");
            scanf("%s", &s.id);
            printf("\nEnter new name :");
            scanf("%s", s.name);
            printf("\nEnter age :");
            scanf("%s", &s.age);
            printf("\nEnter new position :");
            scanf("%s", &s.position);

            fseek(fp, -recsize, SEEK_CUR);
            fwrite(&s, recsize, 1, fp);
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("\nWant to modify another record (Y/N) :");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", &another);
    while (another == 'y')
        modifyrecord();
    while (another == 'n')
        staffmenu();


}

void searchrecord() {
    system("cls");
    int found = 0;
    char namesearch[40];
    char another;

    printf("\n Enter Name to search : ");
    scanf("%s", &namesearch);

    fp = fopen("staff.dat", "rb+");
    rewind(fp);
    while ((fread(&s, recsize, 1, fp) == 1))
    {
        if (strcmp(s.name, namesearch) == 0)
        {
            found = 1;
            printf("Record of Staff / Member of %s is\n", namesearch);
            printf("===================================\n");
            printf("ID : %s\n", s.id);
            printf("Name : %s\n", s.name);
            printf("Age : %s\n", s.age);
            printf("Position : %s\n", s.position);
        }

    }
    if (found == 0)
        printf("Record Not Found\n");
    fclose(fp);
    printf("Search another record(y/n) :");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", &another);
    while (another == 'y')
        searchrecord();
    while (another == 'n')
        staffmenu();


}

void showrecord() {
    system("cls");
    int found = 0;
    char d[20];
    char another;

    printf("\n Enter Member / Staff to show all : ");
    scanf("%s", &d);

    fp = fopen("staff.dat", "rb+");
    rewind(fp);
    while ((fread(&s, recsize, 1, fp) == 1))
    {
        if (strcmp(s.position, d) == 0)
        {
            found = 1;
            printf("Record of Staff / Member\n");
            printf("===================================\n");
            printf("ID : %s\n", s.id);
            printf("Name : %s\n", s.name);
            printf("Age : %s\n", s.age);
            printf("Position : %s\n", s.position);
        }

    }
    if (found == 0)
        printf("Record Not Found\n");
    fclose(fp);
    printf("Search another record(y/n) :");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", &another);
    while (another == 'y')
        showrecord();
    while (another == 'n')
        staffmenu();  
}
```

main.c ( menu )

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)


int main()
{
    int funsType;


    system("cls");
    printf("1) Staff Information\n");
    printf("2) Facility Information\n");
    printf("3) Member Information\n");
    printf("4) Booking Information\n");
    printf("5) Facility Usage Information\n");

    printf("Enter your requirement: ");
    scanf("%d", &funsType);
    switch (funsType) {
    case 1: staffmenu(); break;
    case 2: printf("2"); break;
    case 3: printf("3"); break;
    case 4: printf("4"); break;
    case 5: printf("5"); break;
    default: printf("Please choose the correct number");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Header file

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<conio.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

int menu();
void staffmenu();
```

Comment: 1. Why do you need two `.c` files when `main.c` not doing anything exclusive. 2. Whole project can have only one `main()`, the entry point of the program. 3. Headers are wrong place to define & share variables. 5. Avoid globals as much as possible

Comment: because i only  in charge of one module. main.c is the main menu for the whole system. For the redo.c menu is because i doesn't know how to back to main.c from redo.c. So i create a menu for redo.c

Comment: The header file needs a line `extern FILE *fp;` to declare the file pointer.  One source file defines it.  The other just uses it.

Comment: so I just need put  'extern FILE *fp;' in the header file and define it redo.c and main.c ?

Comment: But you're not using it in `main.c`.

Comment: How to define it in the source file? Just put it in?

Comment: You define it in `redo.c`. I still don't get what you're trying to do.

Comment: the file pointer in int main() is used for all function in redo.c . I put it in main function because I try to put in each function but it cause my program not working

Comment: But isn't all thing inside the main function need to move to Header file when link to header file? So i think is there a way to put the file pointer inside the header file JUST for my modules.